# Curl works but corresponding HttpConnection POST request fails as 400 error

Tags: java, rest, post, curl, httpconnection

Here is my curl request , which works perfectly fine.

curl -X POST http://build-master-mobile.xxx.com:8080/job/Reprovision-IPA/build --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"IPA_URL","value":"xxx"}, {"name":"IPA_FILENAME","value":"xxx.ipa"}]}'

Now I am trying to do this post from my java code using Httpconnection as shown below, but it gives me 400 bad request.
Can the experts help me with this please.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://build-master-mobile.xxx.com:8080/job/Reprovision-IPA/build"); 
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection;
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    String data = "{\"parameter\":[{\"name\":\"IPA_URL\",\"value\":\"xxx\"},{\"name\":\"IPA_FILENAME\",\"value\":\"xxx.ipa\"}]}";

    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    // send request

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `json=` at the start.

Comment: I tried with json= at the start as well, but same 400 error.   String data = "json='{\"parameter\":[{\"name\":\"IPA_URL\",\"value\":\"a\"},{\"name\":\"IPA_FILENAME\",\"value\":\"a.ipa\"}]}'";

Comment: Thanks immibis! Also I was missing the correct contentType to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , it worked now. Thank you Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the content type and json, check below:

```
URL url = new URL("http://build-master-mobile.xxx.com:8080/job/Reprovision-IPA/build"); 
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection;
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

String data = "json='{\"parameter\":[{\"name\":\"IPA_URL\",\"value\":\"a\"},{\"name\":\"IPA_FI‌​LENAME\",\"value\":\"a.ipa\"}]}'";

httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
httpConn.setDoInput(true);
// send request

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
rd.close();
```